# Does BufferedReader lose its performance when wrapped by a Scanner?

Tags: java, performance, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, buffering

Does a `BufferedReader`, which has a buffersize of 8KB lose its performance, when I wrap it in a `Scanner`, which only has a `Buffer` of 1KB?

Comment: Are you asking whether the BufferedReader will still use an 8KB buffer?

Comment: Try it out? Write a small benchmark for your use case?